# Flutter - linear Gradient isnt gradient at all

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I’am scratching my head with this over a week or something and at this point I don’t know what do to.
I admit my Flutter knowledge is pretty low, but from what I know this should not be happening.

I started to play with LinearGradient widget, but it looks like the steps in transition from one color to another is totally random - basically not acting like gradient at all.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  Paint.enableDithering = true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int pocetPiv = 0;
  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          //vrchni lista
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 7, 10, 22),
            title: const Center(child: Text("xxx")),
          ),

          // telo
          body: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color.fromARGB(255, 55, 77, 165),
                  Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 1, 1),
                ],
                stops: [0.25, 0.5],
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

[image: gradient example]

I tried using Stops, erasing them, use (Paint.enableDithering = true) in my main method, tried diferent phone emulators with newer android, but it looks still the same. With darker colors it splits the screen without even trying to merge two colors together.

Something worth mentioning is that when i tried working with "solid" colors - like Colors.red into Colors.blue the gradient looked somewhat normal.

But Hex colors and ARGB is simply not working.

Does anyone experienced something similar ?

Thank you for ur time in advance !

---

Comment: what do you mean doesn't not acting like gradient?

  i just try run your code on dartpad, and its seems works fine

Comment: Thank you, didnt know dart pad had this posibilities. Yeah, dart pad looks pristine, but my Visual code or Android studio emulator doesnt. I have provided screenshot, there you can see the gradient is made of multiple lines which - in my case - are stretched out a LOT . . It is more apparent when i erase the stops. Whole gradient is than made of max 20 lines at best. But thank you, it looks like it is problem of emulator of some sort, because I ran that to web instead of Android emulator and it looks allright.